# Setting to events On Image View

Tags: android

I have created `ImageView` and i want to make two action on it :

First : when i press on the `ImageView` it chnages its Background, to do that, i created `Drawable Resource File` named `imgpressed.xml` and added attribute `android:background="imgpressed` in ImageView Layout

Second : If I click on it (Action UP) , `Toast` should appear on the screen, to do that , I created method `SetOnClickListener` in Java Code
but noticed that when i add attribute android:clickable in imageView , the OnClickListener in code java does not work, and if I remove the Attribute OnClickListener in Java Code works....

that is my codes :

`imageView` Layout :

```html
<ImageView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/imgpressed"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pauseimgS"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="@drawable/pauseimg"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
```

imgpressed.xml :

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/pauseimg"/>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/pauseimgclicked"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Code Java `Main Activity`

```
    public class game extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout Rel_main_game;
    View pauseButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        pauseButton = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.pause, null, false);

        Rel_main_game = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        Rel_main_game.addView(pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(game.this,"Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I can't change background and show Toast in the same time... just one Event is launched

Answer (score 0):

why you have used two backgrounds for your ImageView?!

you should use `android:src="pauseimg"` for your image source
and `android:background="@drawable/imgpressed"` for your background change

also for making your imageview clickable you can use `android:onClick="onImageClick"` and then in your activity:

```
public void onImageClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(game.this,"Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: attribute src is just orthographe mistake when i was writting this post ... when i try ur solution that is message error :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onImageClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'imageView'

Comment: I think because ImageView is inflated